# One to One relationship in Entity Framework MVC

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

I want to create one to one relationship in EF with MVC but getting little bit confused

here are my model...

```
public class Event
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string EventTitle { get; set; }
    public string ImgUrl { get; set; }
    public string Venue { get; set; }
    public int SeatsAvailable { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EventAddedDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

}
```

And

```
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }
}
```

I want to store the Category Id in Event so I created relation in fluentApi like this...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
            .HasRequired(a => a.Category)
            .WithOptional(b => b.Event);
```

but getting this error when updating database...

```
System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmAssociationEnd: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Event_Category_Source' in relationship 'Event_Category'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.
```

Comment: Perhaps this helps:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35639341/configuring-many-one-to-one-relationships-with-entity-framework-code-first-and-f?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

See the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18726038/4254779

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
        .HasKey(t => t.Id);

modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
    .HasRequired(a => a.Category)
    .WithOptional(b => b.Event);
```

Answer (score 0):

EF is not going to let you create a one to one relationship between two entities with independent PKs and mapping a FK property at the same time.This is because of Entity Framework’s requirement that the primary key of the dependent entity should be used as the foreign key too.

```
public class Principal
{
  [Key]
  public Guid Id{get;set;}

  public virtual Dependent Dependent{get;set}
}

public class Dependent
{
  [Key,ForeignKey("Principal" )]
  public Guid PrincipalId{get;set;}

  public virtual Principal Principal{get;set}
}
```

To resolve this issue, remove the FK property from `Event` and remove the `ForeignKey` attribute from `Category` navigation property. The Fluent Api configuration is not needed in this case.

```
public class Event
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    //public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    //[ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: So how would I store the categoryId when I'll create Event of particular category.

Comment: EF will do for you. If you check your DB you will see you still  have a Fk, but EF is who is going to manage that Fk in case you set the Category navigation property